# Convert IObservable<byte[]> with irregular length byte arrays to IObservable<byte[]> with regular length arrays

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an `IObservable<byte[]>` that gives me an uncertain amount of bytes in the byte array. I want to know how I go from that, to returning an `IObservable<byte[]>` with a set amount of bytes in each byte array. Let's assume we want 10 bytes at a time.

That is to say, if I get the following input if I were to subscribe:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
{5, 6}
{7, 8, 9}
{10}
{11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
{16}
{17, 18}
{19, 20}

Bytes.Subscribe(b => Console.WriteLine(b.Length));
```

The output would be

```
3
2
3
1
5
1
2
2
```

What I would like is to convert the input above into this:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
{11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}

Bytes.<WhateverItTakesToDoThat>.Subscribe(b => Console.WriteLine(b.Length));
```

The output would be

```
10
10
```

It must also work if an amount of bytes come in that are larger than a single output packet, i.e.:

```
{21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32}
{33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41}
{42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52}
```

Should be turned into

```
{21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30}
{31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40}
{41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50}
```

(and be holding on to {51, 52}, waiting for more input to come along)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy. Try this:

```
    Bytes
        .SelectMany(b => b)
        .Buffer(10)
        .Select(bs => bs.ToArray());
```

Comment: In my version of Rx (1.0.10621) SelectMany only returns IEnumerable<byte> from that, and IEnumerable<> does not have a Buffer extension method, so I had to add a ToObservable() call between SelectMany() and Buffer(). After that, it works beautifully, thank you. :-)

Comment: @Alex - That would mean that `Bytes` is an `IEnumerable<byte[]>` and not `IObservable<byte[]>` as the question suggests. Try putting the `ToObservable` before the `SelectMany`. That should work too.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. That's my fault; during testing I used an IEnumerable<byte[]> to fake the input without remembering to do a ToObservable() on it first. The real input will be IObservable<byte[]> directly. Sorry about the misunderstanding. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with one solution after a bit of thinking and tinkering. The following code does what I want:

```
Bytes.Select( b => b.ToObservable() ) // Convert input to IObservable<IObservable<byte>>
.Merge( 1 ) // Merges the IObservable<IObservable<byte>> to an IObservable<byte>
            // with the bytes in the right order
.Buffer( 4 ) // Wait until we have 4 bytes ready
.Select( bl => bl.ToArray() ) // Take these 4 bytes and turn them back into an array
.Subscribe( b => Console.WriteLine( b.Length ) );
```

This is probably inefficient, and I'm almost certain it's not he most efficient way of doing this, so if somebody out there can come up with a better, more efficient solution, I'm all ears!